# Adding list of subtypes to list of supertypes in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Let's say I have following interface and class:

```
interface Attachable
class Image: Attachable
```

and following list:

```
val attachableList = listOf<Attachable>(Image(),Image(),Image())
```

In this case how can I add list of attachables to the list of images?

```
var imageList = arrayListOf<Image>().addAll(attachableList)
// Error: Type mismatch. Required: Collection<Image>, Found: List<Attachable>
```

The obvious soultion is to map it explicitly like:

```
val imageList = arrayListOf<Image>().apply{addAll(attachableList.map{it as Image})}
```

But I'm interested in a soultion described in [the article about variance in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `imageList` may only contain instances of type `Image`. However, `attachableList` contains instances of type `Attachable`. Since other classes than `Image` may implement `Attachable`, you cannot safely add all elements from `attachableList` to `imageList`.

If you're sure that `attachableList` only contains instances of type `Image`, using `it as Image` is fine (though there's also `.filterIsInstance<Image>()`. I don't see a way around this using the variance features.

Comment: You should focus on `filterIsInstance` and explain shortly. It looks like the best and right way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can just say `imageList.addAll(attachableList as List<Image>)` if you're sure that `attachableList` will only contain images.

You will receive an unchecked cast warning, but no compiler error.

```
val attachableList: List<Attachable> = listOf(Image(), Image())
var imageList = arrayListOf<Image>()
imageList.addAll(attachableList as List<Image>)
println(attachableList)
println(imageList)
println(imageList == attachableList)
```